# View following finger from Bottom to Top

Tags: android

My problem is i have a screen and a Footer layout at a bottom (Footer always show) and if i touch on Footer and drag it to the top then it move to top and it will show another activity, this footer like Title of 2nd Activity.

I want this footer follow my finger touch.

I don't know how to do that. So please help me !
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom view and override `onTouchEvent()`.  Handle the various action flags in that method (`ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_MOVE`, `ACTION_UP`).  The `onTouchEvent` method receives information about the coordinates of the touch in progress.  A drag will essentially be an `ACTION_DOWN` followed by tons of `ACTION_MOVE` as the finger slides across the screen, and finally an `ACTION_UP` when it's done.  Use the updated coordinates at each call to set the Y translation of your custom view.

Comment: Hi, can you give some examples?